# What is the purpose of dbo:wikiPageDisambiguates in dbepdia?

Tags: dbpedia, spotlight-dbpedia

I try to figure out the purpose of the `dbo:wikiPageDisambiguates`  in DBpedia. I cannot find a definition what it means
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may find this is clarified by looking at [the original Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrard) from which [the DBpedia page](https://dbpedia.org/page/Gerrard) was derived.

Bluntly, some Wikipedia entities are identified *ambiguously*, e.g., the string "Gerrard" may be meant to refer to any of the listed entities.  A *disambiguation page* is then created, such that someone searching for "Gerrard" is presented with a list of the entities they might have meant, such that they can (for instance) view the page about [Paul Gerrard](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Paul_Gerrard) (an entity of type [person](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person)) and not a page about [Gerrard Street](http://dbpedia.org/resource/Gerrard_Street) (a named roadway), which happens to exist in both London and Ontario -- so there's another disambiguation page, so you can see the page about the street in the city you care about.

These pages are not necessarily exhaustive, as Wikipedia and DBpedia are living resources, growing and evolving as people add and correct and adjust data.

It would probably be good if some version of the above were put into the description of [`dbo:wikiPageDisambiguates`](https://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageDisambiguates)